# Android Kotlin - Can't call onNavigationItemSelected method

Tags: android, kotlin

I made drawer menu in Kotlin and I want to use this menu items. In java I was calling `onNavigationItemSelected` method but when I want to use it in Kotlin it doesn't appearing. Here is my code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    tools:context="com.example.zamknijryjx.liobrus.UserActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Imie"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is `navigation_menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="Home"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_sprawdziany"
        android:title="Sprawdziany"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_prace"
        android:title="Prace klasowe"/>

</menu>
```

And code in my Activity:

```
mToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close)
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle!!)
mToggle!!.syncState()

supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

    if (mToggle!!.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

So I want to make something like this: When user click menu item with id for example `nav_home` it makes toast. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can give your `NavigationView` an ID in your layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    ... >
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

And then add a listener to it in your `UserActivity`:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            // handle click
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how can I start new activity with this ?

Comment: You can write any code inside the block where you handle the click of the navigation item - just write the code that starts the new `Activity` there. If you don't know how to do that, you should look at some beginner tutorials on Android first.

Comment: hi, kindly checkout this question thanks in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52710582/nav-header-main-not-displaying-textvalues-from-mainactivity-kt

Comment: This works but messes with the navigation controller if you are using one of those.

Answer (score 1):

@zsmb13 's code works but somehow messes with closing drawer.

I edited code as below, and it works fine

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_gallery -> {
                handleGalleryOption()
                if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                }
                true
            }
            else -> {
                if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                }
                false
            }
        }
    }
```