# NavigationView onNavigationItemSelected is not called

Tags: android, kotlin

yesterday i set my first NavigationView and I would like to add listeners to menu items. I was trying to do it by this: [Android Kotlin - Can't call onNavigationItemSelected method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240735/android-kotlin-cant-call-onnavigationitemselected-method) but it seems like the onNavigationItemSelected is not called.

What did I do.

1.I added NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener to main class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```

2.Settings listeners:

```
val mNavigationView = findViewById<View>(R.id.nav_view) as NavigationView
            mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

3.overided method onNavigationItemSelected

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "hello there")
    return true
}
```

And I expected that should it, but its probably not called.
Can you please help me?

Comment: P.S. you can write just val mNavigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was cause by creating new activity for logging user.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_with_nav)

    val mNavigationView = findViewById<View>(R.id.nav_view) as NavigationView
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    //start login action
    // In the future I will check here some session, but for debbuging I want to log every time
    if(true){
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

After loggin i changed view to the main view but didn't finish that login activity. So all I had to do call finish() after changing view back to main view.

```
activity.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_with_nav);
activity.finish()
```